# How can I connect Google App Engine to Elastic Cloud?

Tags: google-app-engine, elasticsearch-py

I'm trying to connect to my cluster on Elastic Cloud using elasticsearch-py on GAE, but I'm running into the following error:

> ConnectionError: ConnectionError('VerifiedHTTPSConnection' object has no attribute '_tunnel_host') caused by: AttributeError('VerifiedHTTPSConnection' object has no attribute '_tunnel_host')

I've tried this fix that I've seen in a number of places already that reference the '_tunnel_host' error, but it's not resolving my issue:

```py
from requests_toolbelt.adapters import appengine 
appengine.monkeypatch()
```

I've also tried a few variations that I've seen for the es declaration, but none of them have worked; for example:

```py
es = Elasticsearch(["https://elastic:password@xxxxx.us-central1.gcp.cloud.es.io:9243"],
                   send_get_body_as='POST',
                   use_ssl=True,
                   verify_certs=True)
```

I'd like to be able to establish the connection and begin sending and consuming data from my cluster, but can't find a way to do this.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There is an article with example of [real word app Elasticsearch on Google Cloud with Firebase functions](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/click-to-deploy-images/elasticsearch).

On the other hand there is Google Cloud Marketplace with many available Elasticsearch solutions, for example:

> 1.You can deploy and configure [Elasticsearch Cluster](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/google/elasticsearch) that works with kubernetes, using Google Click to Deploy containers.
>
> 2. Or [Elasticsearch complete solution](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/click-to-deploy-images/elasticsearch) using virtual machines provided by Google.